# Which standard specifies the AT&W AT command?

Tags: standards, modem, at-command

While discussing how to process AT commands with a colleague,
we discovered that contrary to our belief the command
`AT&W` (store user profile) is not specified in V.250
(it only specifies `ATZ` and `AT&F`, which are related),
leaving us wondering - where is it specified then?

Update: Yes, we expected the command to have its origin in the
Hayes command set, virtually all the basic syntax commands does.
However, most of the Hayes command have been imported into formal
standards like [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) by ITU or [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) by 3GPP.
Since V.250 did not import this command we were wondering
that it might be because it was specified in some other standard.

And in any case other standards have defined various commands.
Here is an extract from a comment I put in the source code
when I were working with the `AT+VTS` command last year
(which has by the way the most non-standard
parameter syntax I have ever seen!).

> The AT+VTS command originally
>   originates from the standard
>   TIA/EIA/IS-101, "Facsimile Digital
>   Interfaces - Voice Control Interim
>   Standard for Asynchronous DCE" from
>   1993 by Telecommunications Industry
>   Association. This specification is now
>   withdrawn and the AT+VTS command is
>   now specified in ITU-T V.252
>   "Procedure for control of V.70 and
>   H.324 terminals by a DTE".

Does anyone have a reference to a formal standard/documentation
(like above) that defines `AT&W` ? We are not just looking for
manufacturer documentation of some random modem (unless for the original Hayes modems).

Comment: Modem market share determined the de facto standards, it never had to be formalized. Hayes started it all, but they didn't remain top dog for long. I'd check U.S.Robotics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching I think I have found answers to what I was looking for, however please add additional answers if you happen to have a reference to a standard containing `AT&W`.

### Hayes documentation

While I have not found any manual for the Smartmodem 1200 or Smartmodem 2400 modems,
I found a paper called [Technical Reference for Hayes Modem Users](https://totseans.com/totse/en/technology/telecommunications/trm.html)
which says the following about `AT&W`:

```
&W - Write Active Profile to Memory

The &W command stores certain command options and S-register values into 
one of the modem's two nonvolatile stored profile memory locations. The 
command options and register values stored depend on the particular 
modem. These are indicated in the user documentation for your modem. 
In addition, the AT speed and parity are stored, according to the values 
used at the time the command is issued.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
&W0     Store the Active Profile into Stored Profile 0
&W1     Store the Active Profile into Stored Profile 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I assume this covers more or less all modems made by Hayes, so I think this probably is the most official reference I get.

### Other standards

An (older) alternative specification to V.25ter/V.250 is TIA/EIA-602 with title "Data Transmission Systems and Equipment - Serial Asynchronous Automatic Dialing and Control". According to [Information On Hayes command set](http://www.reachinformation.com/define/Hayes_command_set.aspx):

> TIA/EIA-602 is almost identical to the
>   data-specific commands found in the
>   Smartmodems 1200 and Smartmodem 2400

but the specification is not including everything,
TIA/EIA-602 is also [referred to](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/modems/blinddial.html) as the "Minimal AT Command Set".
According to Frank Durda's [AT Ampersand-Prefixed Command Set Reference](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/modems/at/ampersand-at.html)

> The EIA/TIA-602 standard only
>   specifies three AT commands with
>   ampersand prefixes: &C, &D and &F. All
>   other AT commands with ampersand
>   prefixes derive either from the Hayes
>   Smartmodem 2400, Hayes Ultra 14,400 or
>   are proprietary features of other
>   makers.

Which I then interpret to mean that either Hayes Smartmodem defines `AT&W` but EIA/TIA-602 does not import it (most likely) or that it was introduced after the creation of EIA/TIA-602 at some point (no so likely).

Anyone that has access to an original Hayes Smartmodem manual?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? An explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm very thankful that you pasted the bit about `&W`, but I would also have liked to read the paper. Several of the links on your post don't appear to work, can you please update them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called the Hayes command set, popularized by the Hayes modem.  It was a "[de facto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto)" standard long before it was adopted by V.250.

Wikipedia has a [brief description and history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set), and Microsoft has a [summary of the command set](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164660).