# (AT-command in gsm modem) AT+CMGF value change after reboot

Tags: gsm, at-command

my problem is : 
after set AT+CMGF = 1 ( for Text mode SMS), everything work well until  GSM modem reboot
After reboot, AT+CMGF? command return 0 , this means modem need re-config for CMGF parameter.

Please help to save the config value even after reboot.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional modem way to store configuration settings is through *profiles*, controlled with AT command `AT&W`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388889/23118) for some details about that command. Now if your particular modem supports more than one profile and if the `AT+CMGF` mode is included is another question, but at least `AT&W` is what I would start investigating around.