# ESP8266MOD-12F Wifi module, AT Commands

Tags: wifi, at-command, esp8266

I am trying to use ESP8266 and it's my first time to use WIFI module,

I have some question,

How can I translate the AT Command response?,

Can I just use it out-of-box or Do I have to update it's SDK? if No, I have to update it,then How can I update it through my MCU?

I've established connection with it and when I send

`"AT+GMR\r\n"`

it responds with

`"AT+GMR\r\r\nAT+GMR\rb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb+R+Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tv0(205Do\rnhC\r1S08\rOMGs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\nr4u1:Kn\nkno\n.e1:\nETA\n.MyA\n.MyA\n.MyA\n.MyA\n.MyA :0 :\ns.heydd2 :OR+Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb""AT+GMR\r\r\nAT+GMR\rb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb+R+Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tv0(205Do\rnhC\r1S08\rOMGs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\n\r.Gs\nr4u1:Kn\nkno\n.e1:\nETA\n.MyA\n.MyA\n.MyA\n.MyA\n.MyA :0 :\ns.heydd2 :OR+Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb.R Tb"`

I understand that it should be version of AT command and SDK version. But it doesn't look like it is any useful data(excuse my confusion) so how can I understand it?

one more question, is there any useful documentation or datasheet for it? i am asking this because all what i can find online is for specific target or for arduino

Comment: I can't help you with your question but I'd be interested why you would want to use AT commands rather than program Arduino or NodeMCU?

Comment: I am using Tiva C TM4C123 microcontroller to connect to ESP via UART, The reason I am using this microcontroller is that I want to use mbed-OS for IoT solution

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought about such use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage like that could be due to mismatching baud rates. Have you tested with different speeds? If not you should iterate over all common baud rates to see if one of them works. Classical modems supported autobauding, but that is not very common for embedded wifi modules.

Also, notice that the clock speed of your microcontroller significantly influences what baud rates you can use reliably, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685774/23118) for more details.