# SIM800L Date and Time is not working. How to convert from int to string?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino-uno, at-command, sim800, sim800l

I am currently working on a device and it sends data to Firebase. Unfortunately, I am unable to send the correct time and date.

[CONVERT TIME INT TO STRING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiPLs.png)

I tried setting the time but it ignores the changes.

AT+CLTS=1 should enable network time sync.
AT+CLTS? will check if it is set.
AT&W should save the setting in permanent memory.
AT+CCLK? should display the correct time in the end.

[SET TIME AND NETWORK TIME NOT WORKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXIja.png)

Comment: Please include the code (and output) as **text** directly here in the question.

Comment: What does `waitResponse` do? Is it parsing the responses from the modem and waiting for a final result code?

Answer (score 0):

The `AT&W` command [most likely does not save gsm network settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685774/23118) .

String arguments to at commands **must** be enclosed with double quotes, e.g. `AT+CCLK="..."`.