# Commands are not recorded on the SIM7080G GSM modem

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-card

I'm trying to figure out the SIM7080G module. An error occurs with some queries. To see the error code, send the command `AT+CMEE = 1`.

The problem is that I send this command and I get the answer `OK`. Next, I check if the value was written and see that it remains the same, equal to “0”.

Some commands have the same behavior. For example, with the command `AT + CNMP = 13` I want to select the operating mode “GSM”, but the value remains equal to 38 - “LTE”.

But for example, with the command `AT + IPR = 115200` I change the baudrate and it is correctly set.

Please tell me what could be the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Next, I check if the value was written..."_ What do you mean with "next"? Soon after or after a reboot?

Comment: I checked the value immediately after writing, but it turned out that the module had time to reboot. Now the problem is already solved and described in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73639628/sim7080g-gsm-modem-module-cannot-detect-the-network).

Comment: That's what I suspected. If you agree, I would write an answer explaining the scenario and how to avoid settings loss also in case of reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reboot probably occurred between the set command and the subsequent read command.

Commands parameters can be designed with three different behaviors:

1. Never saved after reboot
2. Always saved after reboot
3. Saved in a specific profile section (this is usually the case for ETSI standard commands)

Apparently SIM7080G module don't support profile sections. Anyway, for every command, "Parameter Saving Mode" is specified in the [AT command guide](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/39/SIM7080_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.02.pdf).

The options are:

> **NO_SAVE**: never saved through reboot.
>
> **AUTO_SAVE**: The parameter of the current AT command is saved in NVRAM
> automatically, it takes effect immediately, and it won't be lost if module is rebooted.
>
> **AUTO_SAVE_REBOOT**: The parameter of the current AT command is saved in NVRAM
> automatically, it takes effect after reboot, and it won't be lost if module is rebooted.
>
> **-**: "-" this AT command doesn’t care the parameter saving mode

Comment: Some related [history on what's saved or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965935/23118) of settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when setting to 13 (GSM Only)

It turns out the SIMCOM 7080G is LTE-M & NB-IoT only, GSM isn't supported which would explain this. It's a shame the AT+CNMP=? command shows it as an option and when setting to 13 the modem doesn't respond with ERROR rather than OK.