# SIM7080G GSM modem module cannot detect the network

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-card

I'm trying to figure out the SIM7080G module.
The problem is related to the fact that I can not connect to a cellular operator. The SIM card I am using is working. Checked on a smartphone.

I met a similar situation on the forums ([link](https://community.hologram.io/t/sim7080g-cant-find-any-networks/4527/6), [link](https://community.hologram.io/t/sim7080g-not-finding-any-networks/4450)), but there is no final solution anywhere. Next, I lay out a series of commands that I run to determine the states.

```
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY
OK

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 99.99
OK

AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","Internet"
OK

AT+CNMP
+CNMP: 38
OK

AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 0
OK

AT+CGNAPN?
+CGNAPN: 0,””
OK

AT+COPS?
+COPS: OK

AT+CNACT=1,1
+APP PDP: 0,DEACTIVE

AT+COPS=?
+COPS: ERROR

AT+CGATT=1
+CGATT: ERROR
```

I will say in advance that I can not display the error code. Described the problem here.

Could this be because the SIM card I'm using doesn't work with either NB-IoT or CAT-M? As I understand it, it should work with GSM and it suits me, but now nothing comes out.

I often saw advice to check the power that is supplied to the module. A little later, there will be an opportunity, I'll check.

Please tell me what could be the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
It consisted in the wrong organization of the power supply of the module.
In response, I received a number of responses from the module (RDY, CFUN: 1, CPIN: READY, SMS Ready), which indicated that the module was restarted.
The specification describes how to apply signals to the VBAT and PWKEY pins and hold the desired time. When I corrected the initialization, everything worked.

Also, the module does not really work in the GSM network and is intended exclusively for NB-IoT and CAT-M.