# How to enter an option during voice calls using at commands

Tags: command, gsm, at-command, dialing

I've been using a sim900 module to replicate many of the functions found in a basic cellphones for an embedded project. I've been successful with most functions with the exception of entering options during a voice call. I am actually looking for a generic solution (e.g. GSM 07.07 etc.) although the GSM/GPRS Module I'm using is the sim900.

Scenario: I initiate a call using `ATD<number>;` ,then automated voice asks me to dial "1" for an option. How do I send the "1"?

I've search high and low for an answer. I've been through the AT command manual over and over again. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Very good start in using the official GSM specification, although I want to note that 07.07 has been superseded by [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) a very long time ago, and you should use that document (or 27.005 if relevant).

---

I initially expected there to be two ways of achieving this, dial string modifiers or DTMF command, but I looking up the dial string in the 27.007 specification I do not find the `p` (pause) modifier<sup>1</sup> I was expecting, and nearest thing, the `W` (wait) modifier is ignored and only included for compatibility.

Sending `0` through `9`, `A` through `D`, `*` and `#` during a call is done using [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling), although in a GSM network this is signalled separately out of band rather than sending in-band analogue tones. There is a specific command for sending DTMF tones called `AT+VTS` (with a [horrible syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373635/23118)). So that command is the answer to you question. Invoke it either from online command mode or from another serial connection.

---

<sup>1</sup> The reason I was expecting a `p` modifier to exist is that I am able to enter one in phone book entries, e.g. `"12345678p123" which will dial 12345678, wait for the connection to be established and then send 123 as DTMF tones. But this is then obviously something (only) the user interface voice call handler manages and not the AT command handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will mark as answered as soon as I've tried it. Perhaps conclude with example.

Comment: [SOLVED]Thank you very much for your answer. It worked perfectly: 'AT+VTS= 1'