# In Experimenting with Basic AT Commands: how is manipulation of network data altering account balances possible with python

Tags: python, at-command

Am trying to send request with AT command using python with the help od GSM modem or module, I actually want to manipulate or similutae the balance on the modem using AT command code so that my code will intercept real life the Simulated the balance and send the sms to mobile numbers specified in the code. the Simulated balance I input will be what my modem software Will recognize and send the message or sms text, below code is the code used in actualizing sms sending

```
`# Configure the serial port (replace with your specific port)
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)

import serial
import time
def read_phone_numbers(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        phone_numbers = [line.strip() for line in file]
    return phone_numbers

def send_sms(phone_number, message):
    try:
        # Send SMS using AT commands
        ser.write(b'AT\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        ser.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')  # Set SMS mode to text
        time.sleep(1)
        ser.write(f'AT+CMGS="{phone_number}"\r'.encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        ser.write(message.encode() + b'\x1A')  # Send the message and Ctrl+Z to end
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'SMS sent to {phone_number}')

        # Read the modem response (optional)
        response = ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode('utf-8')
        print('Modem response:', response)
    except serial.SerialException as se:
        print('Serial port exception:', str(se))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to send SMS:', str(e)). But I want to modify 
    finally:
        # Close the serial port
        ser.close()

# Usage
phone_numbers = read_phone_numbers('phone_numbers.txt')
message = 'This is a test message from Python using GSM modem.'

for phone_number in phone_numbers:
    send_sms(phone_number, message) 
And check sms balance import serial
import time

# Configure the serial port (replace with your specific port)
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)

def check_balance():
    try:
        # Send AT command to check balance (hypothetical example)
        ser.write(b'AT+CUSD=1,"*123#",15\r')
        time.sleep(1)

        # Read and print the modem response
        response = ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode('utf-8')
        print('Balance response:', response)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to check balance:', str(e))
    finally:
        # Close the serial port
        ser.close()
```

## Usage

```
check_balance()

import serial
import time

# Configure the serial port (replace with your specific port)
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)

def check_balance():
    try:
        # Send AT command to check balance (hypothetical example)
        ser.write(b'AT+CUSD=1,"*123#",15\r')
        time.sleep(1)

        # Read and print the modem response
        response = ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode('utf-8')
        print('Balance response:', response)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to check balance:', str(e))
    finally:
        # Close the serial port
        ser.close()

# Usage
check_balance()

`
```

But I couldn't actualize the result of manipulating the balance and use it to send sms

Comment: At a first glance your AT commands sequence looks ok, to me. So what's actually the problem? What do you mean with "couldn't actualize the result of manipulating the balance and use it to send sms"? Do you mean you don't know how to parse "response"? Please include to the question what is printed on screen when your program runs.

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` This is guaranteed to make your program fail! You must [**READ** and **PARSE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75828932/23118) all responses the modem sends back to you.  In exactly the same way as you never should write a web client that totally ignores the responses the web server sends back you should never totally ignore the responses the modem sends back! Without this fixed your program is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: You are doing some things right like terminating the command line with just `'\r'`, however for `AT+CMGS` you **MUST** [wait for the "\r\n> " response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) before sending the payload. Again `time.sleep` is a disaster receipt that you immediately must stop even thinking about using. It never works. It is as useful as kicking dogs that stand in your way in order to get them to move. *Maybe* you can be lucky and have some dogs move without suffering any negative consequences for kicking them, but don't count on it!