# esp8266 at commands wecbsocket send data

Tags: websocket, at-command

I want to send a buffer to a websocket server in my laptop using STM32 with esp8266 using AT commands
the code is below :

```
 while (1)
  {
      // Establish a TCP connection to your WebSocket server
      ESP8266_SendATCommand("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.0.103\",8765\r\n");
      HAL_Delay(2000);

      // Construct a WebSocket handshake request
      char websocket_request[256];
      snprintf(websocket_request, sizeof(websocket_request),
          "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
          "Host: 192.168.0.103:8765\r\n"
          "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
          "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
          "Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n"
          "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n"
          "\r\n");

      // Calculate the length of the WebSocket handshake request
      int request_length = strlen(websocket_request);

      // Send the WebSocket handshake request
      char rr[64];
      sprintf(rr,"AT+CIPSEND=%d\r\n", request_length);
      ESP8266_SendATCommand(rr);
      HAL_Delay(100);
      ESP8266_SendATCommand(websocket_request);

      // Wait for the response
      HAL_Delay(1000);

      
      // Construct a WebSocket frame 
      char websocket_frame[256];
      snprintf(websocket_frame, sizeof(websocket_frame), "\x81\x0BHello, World!");

      // Calculate the length of the WebSocket frame
      int frame_length = strlen(websocket_frame);

      // Send the WebSocket frame 
      sprintf(rr,"AT+WSSEND=%d\r\n", frame_length);
      ESP8266_SendATCommand(rr);
      HAL_Delay(100);
      ESP8266_SendATCommand(websocket_frame);

      
      HAL_Delay(1000);
```

The mcu connect to the server and disconnect but the data did not received to it and this is the esp8266 response :

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.0.103",8765

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=157


OK
> 
Recv 157 bytes
AT+CIPSEND=256
⸮Hello, World!
busy s...

SEND OK

+IPD,205:HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 11:29:00 GMT
Server: Python/3.11 websockets/11.0.3

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.0.103",8765

ALREADY CONNECTED

ERROR
AT+CIPSEND=157


OK
> 
Recv 157 bytes
AT+CIPSEND=256
⸮Hello, World!
busy s...

SEND OK

+IPD,4:⸮⸮CLOSED
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.0.103",8765

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=157


OK
> 
Recv 157 bytes
AT+CIPSEND=256
⸮Hello, World!
busy s...

SEND OK

+IPD,205:HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 11:29:08 GMT
Server: Python/3.11 websockets/11.0.3

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.0.103",8765

ALREADY CONNECTED

ERROR
AT+CIPSEND=157


OK
> 
Recv 157 bytes
AT+CIPSEND=256
⸮Hello, World!
busy s...

SEND OK

+IPD,4:⸮⸮CLOSED
```

I tried to just connect via http get one time and send the frames but it give me ERROR in each frame.
So can anyone suggest me some solutions ?

Comment: The following is more that just a suggestion: *Stop using `HAL_Delay` as a substitute for [**READING** and **PARSING**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75828932/23118) the responses you get back from the modem*. In exactly the same way as you never should write a web client that totally ignores the responses the web server sends back you should never totally ignore the responses the modem sends back! Without this fixed your program is guaranteed to fail.