# How to send AT response in Python?

Tags: python, command, at-command

I'm sorry if I'm not asking in the right way, but this is my first post here. Until now, I've often been here, but only read. I have an old device that sends an SMS through a Siemens C35i phone when certain activities are detected. The Siemens C35i is an old model and that's why I wanted to cheat the device a bit and connect to it through a Raspberry Pi to read these SMS messages and save them on a server like www. I have no experience in this type of programming, but I managed to connect the device to the Raspberry Pi and read the initial commands sent by the device. At the beginning, the device sends ATE0 and soon after AT+CGMM to make sure that the C35i phone is connected. I managed to write a program that responds, but the device reads only the first two characters of the response, which is C3, and the rest is cut off. What can I do to make the Raspberry Pi respond with the full identifier? Where can I make corrections? Here's my program:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200) # ustawienia portu COM

at_file = open("AT.dat", "a") # otwarcie pliku AT.dat do zapisu
serial_file = open("serial.dat", "a") # otwarcie pliku serial.dat do zapisu

while True:
    data = ser.readline() # odczytanie jednej linii danych z portu COM
    data_str = data.decode("cp1252").strip() # konwersja danych na string

    if "AT+CGMM" in data_str: # jeśli transmisja zawiera kody AT
        response = "C35i"
        # Wysłanie odpowiedzi
        ser.write((response + "\r\n").encode("cp1252"))
        print(response)
        at_file.write(data_str + "\n") # zapis do pliku AT.dat
    else:
        serial_file.write(data_str + "\n") # zapis do pliku serial.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have no experience in this type of programming

Then the first document you should start reading is the [V.250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en), most importantly chapter 5
(just to emphasis how important that document is: Even after working with implementing AT command in mobile phones in Ericsson for over a decade I and my colleagues still [consulted that standard regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373635/23118)).

Specifically for your scenario when emulating a modem (called DCE in V.250) your code is lacking sending a *Final result code* after receiving an AT command line from your old device (referred to as DTE from now on in this answer). Final result codes are `OK`, `ERROR` and several other responses<sup>1</sup>. This is covered in chapter "5.7 DCE responses".

In fact after sending the first `ATE0` command line the DTE should be expecting **and waiting** for a final result code before continuing, so it would be perfectly within acceptable behaviour for that to be the only command line it sent since it did not receive a response.

The only reason for the DTE to continue with sending `AT+CGMM` after it failed to receive a response for `ATE0` I assume is some thinking like *"`ATE0` and similar is only initialization commands, if they in some way fails then continue nevertheless and hope things still work out"*.

So you need to restructure your code a bit so that you:

1. Buffer incoming data until you have received a complete and full command line (see chapter "5.2 DTE commands lines") **and then and only then start parsing the command line**.
2. Consider if you want to support aborting of commands - you most likely will get away by not supporting it in your case, but let it be a conscious decision.
3. Parse the command line and execute each command that is present.
4. After the command line is finished executing send back a final result code.

---

<sup>1</sup>
While text result codes are the norm note that there also theoretical is a possibility for them to be delivered as numerical values with `ATV0`. So if the DTE sends that command you should honour it.